# Sweetalert2 Swal fire disappears after popup. Very strange error

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Whenever the following function is called with success 1, the Sweetalert dialog disappears immediately after opening and the location reload() works. It is exactly the same code when number_of_errors > 0 but in the latter case, the sweetalert stays open. How do i make it to stay open when success is 1

Note: this function is called from another sweetalert function as a result of an ajax call. Also, the success/error icons don't show up :-( . The css and js files are well referenced in the HTML

Any thoughts will be very welcome, please

Thanks in advance

```
function show_comment_result(
    success,
    number_of_errors,
    error_messages,
    action
) {
    if (action == "new item") {
        html_success = "The item was successfully added";
        html_errorA =
            '<p>We had an <font color="#ff0000">error</font>: <p>' +
            '<p><font color="#ff0000">' +
            error_messages +
            '</font></p><b><a href="#" id="temp2" onclick="restart_entry(); ">Please Try Again</a></b>';
        html_errorB =
            '<p> <font color="#ff0000">UNKNOWN error occured</font>: <p><b><a href="#" id="temp2" onclick="restart_entry(); ">Please Try Again</a></b>';
    } else if (action == "edit item") {
        html_success = "The item was successfully edited";
        html_errorA =
            '<p>We had an <font color="#ff0000">error</font>: <p>' +
            '<p><font color="#ff0000">' +
            error_messages +
            "</font></p>";
        html_errorB = '<p> <font color="#ff0000">UNKNOWN error occured</font>';
    } else if (action == "delete item") {
        html_success = "The item was successfully deleted";
        html_errorA =
            '<p>We had an <font color="#ff0000">error</font>: <p>' +
            '<p><font color="#ff0000">' +
            error_messages +
            "</font></p>";
        html_errorB = '<p> <font color="#ff0000">UNKNOWN error occured</font>';
    }

    if (success == 1) {
        Swal.fire({
            type: "success",
            title: "Success!",
            icon: "success",
            showConfirmButton: true,
            html: html_success
        });
        if (action == "edit item" || action == "delete item") {
            location.reload();
        } else if (action == "new item") {
            document.getElementById("HiddenForm").reset();
        }
        //$('#HiddenForm')[0].reset();
        if (action == "new item") {
            document.getElementById("HiddenForm").reset();
        }
    } else {
        if (number_of_errors > 0) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "error",
                titleText: "Ooops",
                title: "Ooops...",
                showConfirmButton: false,
                html: html_errorA
            });
        } else {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "error",
                showConfirmButton: false,
                titleText: "Ooops",
                title: "Ooops...",
                html: html_errorB
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
Swal.fire({
            type: "success",
            title: "Success!",
            icon: "success",
            showConfirmButton: true,
            html: html_success
        }).then(() => {
        if (action == "edit item" || action == "delete item") {
            location.reload();
        } else if (action == "new item") {
            document.getElementById("HiddenForm").reset();
        }
        //$('#HiddenForm')[0].reset();
        if (action == "new item") {
            document.getElementById("HiddenForm").reset();
        }
})
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I still don't understand why my code hadn't worked. Anyway... just a minor addition. I added an anoymous function to be compatible with IE/Edge which don't support '=>' syntaxes . So '}).then( function() {' instead of '}).then(() => {'